# How to get sorted HashMap from TreeMap in Java

Tags: sorting, hashmap

I would like to just sort my hashMap by key and need some help please.  What I have so far:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> unsortedMapResult = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>(); 

unsortedMapResult.put("Delete Items", "Before items", "After items");
unsortedMapResult.put("Audit Items", "Before items", "After items");

Map<String, Map<String, String>> treeMapResult = new TreeMap<String, 
Map<String, String>>(unsortedMapResult);

Map<String, Map<String, String>> finalResult = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

I am simply walking the TreeMap and copy contents to a new HashMap

```
Set<Entry<String, Map<String, String>>> entrySets = treeMapResult.entrySet();

for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> ent : entrySets) {
  finalResult.put(ent.getKey(), ent.getValue());
}

return finalResult;
```

The problem is finalResult now is NOT sorted and is exactly the same as my initial unsortedMapResult.

I would like to have it so that they are sorted as follow:

```
Audit Items, Before items, After items
Delete Items, Before items, After items
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *no such thing* as a "sorted HashMap", so I'm afraid what you're asking for is simply not possible. As [the documentation for HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) says:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map

Inserting elements in a particular order (which is what you're doing here) will do nothing to make them come out in the order you want, and neither will anything else -- other than using instead a collection (like TreeMap) that *does* respect some kind of ordering of the elements.